# Remapping IMU data in launch file

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam, topics, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there!

I am very new to ROS so forgive me if that's too easy question. I was trying to find some information on this forum and on ros wiki but couldn't find any.

I want to use hector_slam for my mapping project and right now I am experimenting with IMU data and hector_imu_attitude_to_tf . What I am trying to achieve now is to transform my IMU data to tf. My understanding is that in order to do that I need to publish my IMU data on imu_topic.

For experimenting with those ideas I downloaded some bag file with IMU data and created the following simple launch file:

> 

/auk/fcu/imu is the IMU topic on which my bag file publishes. After launching the file rostopic list command lists imu_topic but unfortunately nothing is being published to that topic. The same is with /tf topic. After running roswtf I got the following message:

> WARNING The following node
> subscriptions are unconnected:  *
> /imu_attitude_to_tf_node:    *
> /imu_topic

Should my /imu_topic point to the same data as /auk/fcu/imu ? I would be grateful for any tips about what I might be doing wrong.

I don't know if it's relevant but I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188573/remapping-imu-data-in-launch-file/) by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here your node expects data on `imu_topic` but its available on `auk/fcu/imu`

```
<remap from="imu_topic" to="auk/fcu/imu"/>
```

OR

you can change topic while playing your bag file like

```
rosbag play bag_file.bag /auk/fcu/imu:=/imu_topic
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on 2014-08-01**:
Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately changing launch file as you suggested didn't work for me. Does it matter in which node do I try to remap? Luckily changing topic in bag file worked! For now I will stick with that.